# IAM Role of DynamoDB and Congnito with Facebook

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-facebook

I am using cognito with facebook login in Unity. I want to use dynamodb with cognito credentials. Unauthenticated credential is good to go but authenticated credential shows an error

```
DynamoDB GetItem Error : User: arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXXXX:assumed-role/"my identity pool"/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:GetItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:ap-northeast-1:XXXXXXXXXX:table/"table name"
```

I placed Action "dynamodb:GetItem" in IAM Role, the problem is Condition of IAM Role. If I deleted Condition in IAM Role, it works. But I want to add condition for security. Here is my Condition of IAM Role

```
"Condition": {
            "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                    "${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}"
                ]
            }
        }
```

Please Tell me what to do Thanks..

Comment: Is the partition key in question your identity id? That condition is saying that they can only access rows where the partition key is equal to that identity id (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html)

Comment: Thanks, I deleted Condition for authentication credential to access dynamodb...